# How to configure terminal for all projects

Tags: webstorm

When I'm setting a terminal settings it's marked as a settings for a current project:

[image]

Is there any way to set this setting for all projects from settings dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade your IDE.

Latest **2016.3.2** (must be build 163.9251 or newer) has only "Start directory" as project settings -- all other are IDE-wide.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-164206#comment=27-1749073

[image]
*(screenshot is from PhpStorm 2016.3.2 EAP build)*

---

As for older IDE versions -- try settings it up at `File | Default Settings...` .. but it will affect only future new projects and not current ones.

Comment: thanks, but I'm using the newest version `WebStorm 2016.3.2
Build #WS-163.9166.30, built on December 12, 2016`. `File | Default Settings` is what I needed.

Comment: I'm using PhpStorm .. which is 163.10154 -- and it's there. If latest available WebStorm is only 163.9166 .. then you will have to either wait for 2016.3.3 (if it will come up) .. or 2017.1 EAP builds....

Comment: Looking at the [fixed issues list at their Issue Tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB?q=%23Fixed%20) .. 2016.3.3 seems to be planned.

Comment: P.S. At the same time -- we may see 2017.1 EAP build next week -- https://twitter.com/WebStormIDE/status/809746571235573760